# Listening and sending data between two sites

Tags: php, xmpp

I don't know if there is some name for this but what I want to create a
script in php which runs in the background and capable of sending and receiving messages.

**This is what I want to do exactly:**

1. Listen to a URL http://site1.com through xmpp protocol.
2. Whenrever there is a message from site1.com, I should send it to http://site2.com as GET
3. Listen to http://site2.com for a response (site2 may take >=30mins to respond to message we sent in step2)
4. If a GET a response from site2.com, I should send the message to http://site1.com through xmpp.

**This is what I've done:**

1. Using XMPPHP library, listening to site1.com consistenly through infite while loop.
2. Whenver there is a message, i'm using file_get_contents() to push message to site2.com.
3. Now, I'm struck here. I don't how listen to this site2.com on GET now, as my script is already running and listening to site1.com.
4. Its easy to send a message to site1.com. The only problem is 3rd step.

--

Any idea how I could solve this or any other alternative(better) way I could do this? Any help is appreciated.

PS: I don't have access to both site1.com and site2.com except their urls for sending and receving.

Answer (score 0):

Define sties and run script according to response you get from each url.